# Count the number of sequences of given set

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

> Given $S= {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}}$ ; 
>   How many  infinite sequences can be formed from $S$ elements such that each sequence is both Geometric  and Arithmetic  sequence ?

The answer  is $8$ in the book ; but i don't understand how to get this answer?

Any help will be  appreciated

Thank you for your help

Comment: Only a **constant** sequence is geometric and arithmetic as well. An example is $3,3,3,3,\cdots$.

Comment: @drhab   yes ; you are right  ; Brilliant dr

Answer (score 0):

Hint: If $(a_n)$ is an arithmetic sequence, then we have $a_n=a_0+nd.$ If $(a_n)$ is also geometric, we have $a_n=r^da_0$. Looking at $a_1$, 
$$
a_0+d=ra_0
$$
So $d=(r-1)a_0$. Looking at $a_2$, $a_0+2d=r^2a_0$. Substituting for $d$ gives $a_0+2(r-1)a_0=r^2a_0$, which is a quadratic equation that you can solve for $r$.